# How to get appRoleAssignedTo for Microsoft Azure Applications?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azureportal, azure-service-principal

I am trying to get appRoleAssignedTo for my Azure Tenant, now suppose if I have 10 applications under that tenant I will have to make 10 different calls by passing the servicePrincipal Id for all the 10 applications.

`GET /servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignedTo`

Is there a way through which I can get all the appRoleAssignedTo under respective servicePrincipal using just one API call.

Alternatively Microsoft provides a delta call for servicePrincipal, is there a way that the delta returns me the servicePrincipal when appRoleAssignedTo has changed(basically connecting the appRolesAssignedTo to servicePrincipal)
P.S I have tried doing it using $select and $expand and it doesn't work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with `$expand=appRoleAssignedTo` in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#).

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$expand=appRoleAssignedTo
```

If you want to use both `$select` and `$expand`, the **"id"** is required.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$select=id,displayName&$expand=appRoleAssignedTo
```

The response looks like:

```
{
    "value": [
    {
        "id": "xxxxxx",
        "displayName": "Managed Service",
        "appRoleAssignedTo@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals('xxxxx')/appRoleAssignedTo",
        "appRoleAssignedTo": []
    },
  ....
  ]
}
```

Comment: I want to integrate expand with delta, there is a way to integrate it with delta?

Comment: Unfortunately, `$expand` is not supported for tracking changes. Please see this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview.