# Inconsistent behavior when getting app role assignments for a Service Principal using Graph API/SDK/Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the app role assignments for a Service Principal in my Azure AD and seeing inconsistent behavior.

#### Background

I created an application in my Azure AD and defined some app roles for the same. The application is a single-tenant application. A Service Principal (SP) was created for this application.

I then assigned an app role to some of the users and a group for that SP. This all worked very well.

When I go check the properties of the users and the group for app role assignments, I can see there that proper app role assignments are returned.

#### Inconsistency #1

When I go to "Users and groups" under my SP in Azure Portal, it only lists the users that are assigned app roles. It does not list the group that has been assigned an app role.

I see same behavior when I invoke the Graph API directly. The API I am calling is [`List appRoleAssignments granted for a service principal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Only users are returned and not the group. The URL I am calling here is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<service-principal-id>/appRoleAssignedTo`.

I also see the same behavior when I use `Microsoft.Graph` .Net SDK (version 4.41.0). Here's the relevant snippet of my code:

```
var authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", authProvider)
var request = graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals["my-service-principal-id"].AppRoleAssignedTo.Request();
var response = await request.GetAsync();//response only contains users
```

#### Inconsistency #2

Then I tried the answer provided [How to get appRoleAssignedTo for Microsoft Azure Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683609/how-to-get-approleassignedto-for-microsoft-azure-applications) and called the [`Get servicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with `$expand=appRoleAssignedTo` query parameter. The URL I am calling here is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/<service-principal-id>?$expand=appRoleAssignedTo`

I am able to get the SP details and I also see `appRoleAssignedTo` attribute in the response however this time I only see the group in the response and not the users.

I am wondering why I am seeing this inconsistent behavior and what I can do to get proper app role assignments for a SP.

#### To Summarize:

- List appRoleAssignments granted for a service principal API only returns users and not groups.
- Get servicePrincipal API with $expand=appRoleAssignedTo only returns the group and not the users.

Comment: Have you tried with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{service_principleId}?$select=id,displayName&$expand=appRoleAssignedTo , hope this will work . Thanks

Comment: @vickykumar - Thanks. I have tried that but it does not work. Please look at `Inconsistency #2` in my post.

Comment: When you tried with expand , you are not getting principalType : "User" , right? could please confirm again , because when tried to repo , i am getting users as well .

Comment: In place of checking with individual service principal id , could you please try to check for the list of service principle  - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$select=id,displayName&$expand=appRoleAssignedTo , then search principalType in the response , let me know if you are to get , also add the screenshot .

Comment: Thanks Let me give it a try one more time. Regarding `In place of checking with individual service principal id , could you please try to check for the list of service principle` - I think this is highly inefficient as I would first need to list all Service Principals and then find out information about my Service Principal. Also, I think it is not necessary as well.

Comment: I am having similar issues using v5 of the .NET SDK whenever I want to get the "appRoleAssignedTo" of a serviceprincipal. Retrieving the full ServicePrincipal by its id using `options.QueryParameters.Expand = new[] { "appRoleAssignedTo" }` yields less results than making a call as `client.ServicePrincipals[id].AppRoleAssignedTo.GetAsync()`